# Maven: Multiple properties for activating profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a Maven application that builds a user interface (UI) application using npm and bundles it. I have two Maven profiles to manage the local build process conditionally. I need to activate one of the two Maven profiles during a build based on whether Node is installed on the local system:

1. **No Node:** This profile runs only on the local system and is activated only if Node is not present on the system.
2. **With Node:** This profile runs only on the local system and is activated only if Node is present on the system.

I am using the activation tag to conditionally activate a profile. I need to check two conditions: the environment and the Node environment variable. However, Maven only allows one `property` tag in the activation.

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>No Node</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>env.NODE_HOME</name>
            </property>

            <!-- INVALID -->
            <property>
                <name>local</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <!-- INSTALL NODE AND NPM -->
            <!-- CREATE UI BUILD -->
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>With Node</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>!env.NODE_HOME</name>
            </property>

            <!-- INVALID -->
            <property>
                <name>local</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <!-- CREATE UI BUILD -->
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Is there another way to apply both of these conditions to both profiles?